# Jssor Carousel. Images from <a> tag doesn’t appear after last google chrome update v 45.0.2454.85

Tags: javascript, image, google-chrome, jssor

I'm using Jssor Slider for a carousel. It worked perfectly until the last Google Chrome update to version 45.0.2454.85. The Idea is that it doesn't show the images. Currently they are in an  tag and work on Safari and Firefox but not anymore on Chrome. If I remove the  tag they appear but I need it to work on .

```
<div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1140px; height: 160px; overflow: hidden;">
      @foreach($slideshow_details as $slideshow_detail)
          <div>
               <a href="{{ URL::to('/home_details/show') }}">
                <img u="image" src="/images/{{$slideshow_detail['property_url']}}"/>
              </a>
         </div>
     @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: I found the solution. Add display: block to <a>

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I had this issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

I completely replaced all slider jssor JS files with the current one and worked!. I looked for this solution for over 2 days.